# Nativescript Vue Developer Tools not working

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue, vue-devtools

I am following the tutorial as it is stated here: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/vue-devtools/

I have the dev tools and the app up and running but the dev tools says "Waiting for connection..." while the app is already running on my android emulator.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try rebuilding app after configuring dev tools?

Comment: Yes, and just in case I just tried it again.

Comment: @SinanSamet would you please check my answer I have updated it.

Comment: @SinanSamet did you try 10.0.2.2 as I mention in my answer?

Comment: @SinanSamet can you accept my answer please

Answer (score 0):

**Device and development computers must be in the same network.**

So you need to check if your emulator has a correct connection.

*10.0.2.2* is a special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

- Communication with the emulated device may be blocked by a firewall program running on your machine.
- Communication with the emulated device may be blocked by another
  (physical) firewall/router to which your machine is connected.
  Check your devices with
  `tns device` and `adb devices` then ping to their IP or `telnet localhost 5554`

### Your host computers local IP address can be different but just use 10.0.2.2

```js
Vue.use(VueDevtools, { host: '10.0.2.2' })
```